# Sucess ajax function work when i load the page

Tags: ajax, symfony4

I don't understand why my sucess function work alone without i click on the function after 2 sec i load the page.

```
{% block javascripts %} 
 <script>
  $.ajax({
       url : '{{ path('post_like', {'id' : article.id}) }}',
       type : 'POST',
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(code_html, statut){ 
         $("#likeChange").replaceWith("hello world");
         console.log("test")
     },
       error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
       }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

the content i need to change

```
 <a id="likeChange">{{ article.likes | length }}<a>
```

this is the button to call function

```
 <a data-like="{{ article.id }}" id="ajax" class="btn" role="button"><img src="{{ asset('build/image/flecheup.png') }}"></img></a>
```

Comment: yes because ..your ajax is called on load ? its not under any event handler  nor under any function ?

Comment: Nop i just have this function, i edited the post for you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just don't do a function onClick

```
{% block javascripts %} 
 <script>
$(document).on('click', '#ajax', function(){
   that = $(this);
  $.ajax({
       url : '{{ path('post_like', {'id' : article.id}) }}',
       type : 'POST',
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(code_html, statut, likes){ 
         $("#likeChange").replaceWith(likes);
         console.log("test")
     },
       error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
       }
    });
    return false;
});

</script>
{% endblock %}
```